# Visual Studio 2017 not loading symbols from local directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

For some reason, the debug files for my class are not being loaded from the iis folder.  For instance, I have IIS pointing to my Api path, and the debug files are in the bin directory.  In the modules window though, it shows that they're being loaded from temporary files and not the local directory:

[image]

This also shows up in the symbol load information screen: 
[image]

I've tried all the settings possible (use managed compatability mode, legacy expression, just my code, ms symbol server, clearing hte cache, deleting those folders, rebuilding the project, you name it), and I can't get anything to work.

The closest I can get is use managed compatability mode, but then inspecting lists and certain types don't work correctly.  In all the other things I've tried, the breakpoints are hit but no local variables show up: [image]

Yes, I am using dynamically loaded modules, but this worked with 2013 without issue, and stopped working in 2015 Update 2.  The fixes they've provided do not work for me.

I also can't seem to figure out how to load them from the running directory, and  I feel like this is the root of the issue, but I can't figure out how to do it!  when clicking managed compatibility mode, one of the dynamically loaded dlls gets loaded correctly, but there is still another reference to that same dll in the temp folder: [image]